# How to deep merge arrayPrototype in SymfonyConfiguration

Tags: symfony, configuration

I have following configuration:

```
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('rest_api');
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('exceptions')
                    ->defaultValue([])
                    ->arrayPrototype()
                        ->scalarPrototype()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();
```

And following 2 files in 2 different bundles:

```
rest_api:
  exceptions:
    404:
      - UserNotFoundException
    400:
      - InvalidCredentailsException
```

```
rest_api:
  exceptions:
    404:
      - NotFoundHttpException
    400:
      - SomeRandomException
      - OtherRandomException
```

I wanted the result to look like this:

```
^ array:1 [
  "exceptions" => array:4 [
    404 => array:1 [
      0 => "NotFoundHttpException"
      1 => "UserNotFoundException"
    ]
    400 => array:2 [
      0 => "SomeRandomException"
      1 => "OtherRandomException"
       => "InvalidCredentailsException"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But instead I get this:

```
^ array:1 [
  "exceptions" => array:4 [
    404 => array:1 [
      0 => "NotFoundHttpException"
    ]
    400 => array:2 [
      0 => "SomeRandomException"
      1 => "OtherRandomException"
    ]
    405 => array:1 [
      0 => "UserNotFoundException"
    ]
    406 => array:1 [
      0 => "InvalidCredentailsException"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How can I enable deep merging of arrayPrototypes?

I tried with both using integers and strings as key names, changing keys to something non numeric: `c404`, `c400`, as well as both settings from documentation: `performNoDeepMerging` and `cannotBeOverwritten` but none seem to work.

What I need is something like `performDeepMerging` option or something similar, but I dont see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By default an `arrayNode` is treated like a list, with a numeric index. To force treating it as an associative array, you can define it with `useAttributeAsKey`. Just passing a dummy field name will work without raising an error.

```
// ...
->arrayNode('exceptions')
    ->defaultValue([])
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
// ...
```

There are some excellent examples with the differences in how array nodes are processed in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/5314#issuecomment-105243791).